# no_proxy and http_proxy while installing R package

Tags: r, cran

We have internal local cran mirror which does not need http_proxy to be used.

However for some packages there are third party dependencies which are downloaded from internet. Example stringi downloads something called [1]

So how to say to R to not to use proxy for getting internal mirror.

I tried following and it does not work.

```
Sys.setenv(http_proxy="http://proxydetails.com")
Sys.setenv(https_proxy="http://proxydetails.com")
Sys.setenv(HTTP_PROXY="http://proxydetails.com")
Sys.setenv(HTTPS_PROXY="http://proxydetails.com")
Sys.setenv(no_proxy='localmirror.com')
```

If I keep all of them then i get error [2]
If I comment out http_proxy settings then it gives error [1]

[1]
Error in download.file(paste(href, fname, sep = ""), outfname, mode = "wb"):    cannot open URL 'http://static.rexamine.com/packages/icudt55l.zip'

[2]
Error log

[cloud-user@rstudio-test2 ~]$ sudo ./install.sh
[1] "stringi"
[1] "Checking package  stringi"
Loading required package: stringi
[1] "Installing package  stringi"
Warning: unable to access index for repository http://localmirror/src/contrib
Warning messages:
1: In library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
  there is no package called ‘stringi’
2: package ‘stringi’ is not available (for R version 3.1.2)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and managed to solve it by setting two R options:

- options(download.file.method="curl") : set R download method to curl
- options(download.file.extra = paste0("--noproxy ", *your_internal_cran_hostname*)) : do not use proxy for this specific host

It seems like R default download method only supports no_proxy="*", which is why you have to use curl instead.

You can include these two lines in you R_HOME/etc/.Rprofile to make these changes persistent.

Hope this helps !

PS: if you want to remove red messages printed during download, you can add a "-s" option in download.file.extra